# Update UI state from multiple places

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, realm

I'm using Realm and I have a `List` where each object in it has an `isFavorite` bool property to keep track of if the user favorited the object or not. The challenge is that this property could be changed by the user from multiple places in the app.

There is a heart button (for favoriting), a simple `UIButton`, in 3 places in the app --> anytime one of these buttons are tapped, the property `isFavorite` in that object is updated. Now I'm not sure how to update the image of the `UIButton` in all places of the app when one of the buttons are tapped.

For example, there is one ViewController that sets the heart button (`UIButton`) in `viewDidLoad` - so this is set only once. How will the state of this button update if in another ViewController another heart button is tapped? Note: the `List` is used to populate a `collectionView` which has the favorite buttons in each cell. If you tap a cell, then it goes to another view controller and displays the selected `Image` object

What I believe is the solution is setting up some form of notification with Realm. I watched this video but am still not sure how to execute on this: https://realm.io/news/meetup-jp-simard-mastering-realm-notifications/

Here are the model objects, notice how there is an array of `Image` objects with the `isFavorite` property:

```
import RealmSwift

/// Model class that manages the ordering of `Image` objects
final class ImageList: Object {
    let images = List<Image>()
}

/// Model class for the `Image` objects
final class Image: Object {
    dynamic var isFavorite = false
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi JEL,  in general we can use Singleton class or KVO. https://cocoacasts.com/key-value-observing-kvo-and-swift-3/

Comment: @balagurubaran Can't use a singleton here because there are lots of objects which can be favorited, it isn't just one. As for KVO, I'm curious to know if Realm has some way to do this without KVO

Comment: Update it from viewWillAppear or cellForRowAtIndex, use notifications, use a shared instance manager that each object will register itself as a delegate.. Pick any and ask here if you have trouble with *implementation*.

Comment: @pckill Is there are an _implementation_ that Realm provides for this? Basically is there a solution already to this problem that Realm provides (this is why I tagged the question with `Realm`)

Comment: Yeah, you can use [Realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#notifications) for that. Take a look at [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) as well. I'd say it is an overkill for simple manipulations though.

Comment: @pckill `Object Notifications` from Realm might do the trick but am not 100% sure. By the way I updated my question with the model objects. Using Realm, I think I might have to use the api  `addNotificationBlock` to the `let images = List<Image>()` property in `ImageList`. I think but not sure

Comment: Do you know the Objective-C?

Comment: @0xDatou A little, prefer Swift

Comment: Why using plain Realm notifications wouldn't work in each controller with a button?

Answer (score 0):

In each controller with a button, you set a Realm notification in the init().

```
// Observe Realm Notifications
let token = realm.addNotificationBlock { notification, realm in
    tableView.reload()
}
```

You also set a remove Realm notification in deinit().

```
token.stop()
```

If the controller is removed from the app stack, next time you display it, it will reload all the Realm elements - shouldn't cause a problem.
If the controller is still in the app stack, it will detect the notification and update the UI - shouldn't cause a problem.